# Replace values in a ctypes c_char array

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a program that creates an array of `8192` bytes of data.
Now I want to change the value like below where `returnBuffer` is my array:

```
serialBuff = returnBuffer[0x14:0x28]
DataToWrite = "15510580029600000000"

returnBuffer = returnBuffer.replace(serialBuff, DataToWrite)
```

But the result I got was :

```
AttributeError: 'c_char_Array_8192' object has no attribute
'replace'
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: thanks for the Edit Alex! any idea how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you simply loop over the data and write one at a time at the index you want? (Or use a simple assignment to a range, if `ctypes` supports that.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because arrays don't have a `replace` method. From what I know they have no public facing methods.

In order to replace the contents you could either perform a 1 by 1 assignement (no need to write counters in hex, but it's allowed so why not):

```
for i in range(0x14, 0x28):
    returnBuffer[i] = DataToWrite[i - 0x14]
```

or use slicing (as suggested by @eryksun):

```
returnBuffer[0x14: 0x28] = DataToWrite.encode('utf-8')
```

One of these should do the trick.

As an example with more simple values:

```
In [71]: arr = 5 * ctypes.c_char

In [72]: c_arr = arr("0", "1", "2", "3", "4")

In [73]: print c_arr[:]
01234

In [74]: replaceVals = "321"

In [75]: for i in range(0x1, 0x4):
    ...:     c_arr[i] = replaceVals[i - 0x1]


In [76]: print c_arr[:]
"03214"
```

Or, with slicing:

```
In [77]: c_arr[0x1: 0x4] = raplce.encode('utf-8')
In [78]: c_arr[:]
"03214"
```

Comment: you are awesome! that solved my issue! thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @BarathanR. If this solved your issue, don't hesitate to mark it as accepted for other users to see. :-)

Comment: Using slicing will be *much* faster: `c_arr = (5 * ctypes.c_char)(*b'01234');` `print(c_arr[:]);` `c_arr[0x1:0x4] = b'321';` `print(c_arr[:])`. (written to work on 2.6+ and 3.x)